# Backbone JS model fetch using OPTIONS instead of GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch from a REST endpoint using a model. Here's the code:

```
professors: function(id) {
  professor = new ProfessorModel({
    id: id
  });

  professor.fetch({
    headers: {
      'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN': document.cookie
    },

    success: function(model, response, options) {
      AppController.showView(new ProfessorView({model: model}));
    },

    error: function(model, response, options) {
      AppController.showView(new ErrorView({
        statusCode: response.status,
        errorMessage: response.statusText
      }));
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason, the REST endpoint is telling me that the fetch is using OPTIONS instead of GET.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300874/backbone-fetch-request-is-options-method) answer, but it didn't work. CORS is already enabled on my endpoint and the Backbone.enableHTTP option didn't work either.

I looked at the Backbone source and I can't seem to find anything about it using OPTIONS to make any requests. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What you are experiencing is a CORS preflight. Next time read the [manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0), it is not that long.

Comment: @inf3rno I asked for your help, not your attitude.

Answer (score 1):

The OPTIONS request is an [underlying feature of XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) trigged by your use of a custom HTTP header (`'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN': document.cookie`).

It isn't specific to Backbone, which is why you couldn't find a reference to it in the Backbone source code.

The answer you found is the right one. You need to set up your server to correctly respond to the OPTIONS request.